# Graph execution errror Keras-Tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to fit a keras created sequential neural network to a certain dataset, however I keep running into this compilation error "graph execution error", some help would be very much appreciated.

Here is my code

```
df=pd.read_csv("abalone.csv")

df_train,df_valid=train_test_split(df,train_size=0.7)
y_train,y_valid=df_train.Type,df_valid.Type
X_train,X_valid=df_train.drop("Type",axis=1),df_valid.drop("Type",axis=1)
max_=X_train.max()
min_=X_train.min()

X_train=(X_train-min_)/(max_-min_)
X_valid=(X_valid-min_)/(max_-min_)



model3 = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=[X_train.shape[1]]),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1),
])


model3.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="mae",
)

history = model3.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
    batch_size=256,
    epochs=10,
)

---
```

Comment: What error message in detail do you receive?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more details, but at least your input shape seems to have a problem; try this `input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], )`. Note the comma...

Comment: Please provide the output of `df.head()` to understand the dataset's columns. This code is running perfectly when I tried replicating the same code by replacing the `Type` column with column `Age` of this [abalone dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#in_memory_data). Please check this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/72cefe5225cc9a2a2e9f0bee9bb9dd34/74501483.ipynb) for your reference.